# Custom avatar function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, comments, avatar

Hello I work on WordPress and I have a premium theme which is not supported from the creator anymore so I am trying to make a change; I am not sure that this is called a bug. On comments when a visitor is place a comment; his avatar is not the default 'mystery' in this case (no_avatar.gif) but it automatically takes the avatar of the current post author. I like to shows the default for unregistered users. I would like to notice that the theme is use it's own avatars. I target the code on functions but I am not able to change it, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance here is the code:

```
function tgt_get_avatar_link($user_id = ""){
if (!empty($user_id)){
    $avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image', $user_id);
}
else
$avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image');
if (!$avatar){
    return TEMPLATE_URL . '/images/no_avatar.gif';
}
    return TEMPLATE_URL . $avatar;
}
```

Update: The function is calling `tgt_get_avatar_link` but it seems that is:

```
function tgt_ad_comment($comment, $args, $depth){
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    global $helper;
    ?>
    <li>
    <div class="comment" id="comment-<?php comment_ID()?>">
        <?php //echo get_avatar($comment) ?>
        <?php echo $helper->image(tgt_get_avatar_link($comment->user_id), $comment->comment_author, array('title' => $comment->comment_author, 'width' => '58px', 'height' => '58px'))  ?>
        <div class="comment_content">
            <strong><?php echo get_comment_author_link() ?></strong> <?php _e('Say ','ad')?>(<?php comment_time('F j, Y \a\t g:i a') ?>)
            <br/>
            <?php comment_text() ?>
        </div>

</div>
```

The function is calling `$user_id` but it seems that is:

```
function tgt_get_avatar_link($user_id = ""){
   if (!empty($user_id)){
    $avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image', $user_id);
}
   else
    $avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image'); 
   if (!$avatar){
    return TEMPLATE_URL . '/images/no_avatar.gif';
   }
   return TEMPLATE_URL . $avatar;   
}
```

Comment: This isn't actually enough for us to be able to help you – we need to know what function is calling `tgt_get_avatar_link`, and what `$user_id` it's passing.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for reply! I am not enough familiar with php to answer your question I found better idea to show you all the code. I have upload all the code in zip file so I really need your advice please if you download it and check it, thank you so much here is the link:[Link](http://uploading.com/files/get/8ma35ead/author_widget.zip)

Comment: Sorry, if you're not able to post the code in your question, I'm not going to be able to look at it. And if you're not familiar enough with PHP to answer my question, I'm guessing it might be a stretch for you to apply any answer I could come up with, short of doing all the work for you. It sounds like you might need to hire someone. It's too bad the premium theme is no longer supported, but I imagine the author might have valid reasons.

Comment: Yes it's too bad. Well I think I was able to find what functions is calling `tgt_get_avatar_link` and `$user_id` I have update the question, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the comment author has no defined avatar, you'd like to show a default image. This seems to be the `else` in your conditional:

```
else { $avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image'); }
```

Without a $user_id to pass to [get_the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta), it assumes the user ID of the current post author. This is likely causing the behavior you describe.

Try to remove the `else` statement, skipping straight from `if (!empty($user_id)){$avatar = get_the_author_meta('tgt_image', $user_id);}` to `if (!$avatar){...`. Now, when the function is passed a null user_id, it should `return TEMPLATE_URL . '/images/no_avatar.gif';`

Comment: I have already try this I am sorry I don't mention it, this is solve my issue but is creates new one. If another function is call `tgt_get_avatar_link` is return the blank avatar... as you say I am afraid that that's why author is not support this theme anymore...